# Retrieve Data from Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I seem to be having troubles with my stored procedure call here. I'm trying to get all my information from a stored procedure, which returns a single column into a datatable. I've followed along for most solutions here and can't seem to figure out why it is not working. My data table has a primary key constraint on it, due to having multiple values in it. But, from what I've read, this isn't necessary as the `Fill` on the `SqlDataAdapter` will just merge those changes if there is any?

Here is my code so far:

```
Dim dtValues As New DataTable()

Dim dtCol As New DataColumn()
dtCol.ColumnName = "ReferenceID"
dtCol.DataType = GetType(SqlInt32)
dtCol.AllowDBNull = False

dtValues.Columns.Add(dtCol)
dtValues.PrimaryKey = {dtCol}

Public Shared Sub ExecStoredProc(ByVal ProcName As String, ByRef connection As SqlConnection, ByRef dtValues As DataTable, ByVal ParamArray args() As Object)
    Dim sqlCommand As New SqlCommand()

    For i = 0 To args.Length - 1 Step 2
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(CStr(args(i)), args(i + 1))
    Next

    sqlCommand.CommandText = ProcName
    sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    sqlCommand.Connection = connection

    Dim sqlAdp As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand)
    ' Fill the table to mess around with.
    sqlAdp.Fill(dtValues)

End Sub
```

However, the error that I get is:

> Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

My stored procedure I'm calling is a simple

```
Select ID 
From TableName 
Where Reference = @Reference
```

with no conditions really, and I've tested and it returns about 19 unique records.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Which line are you getting the error on?

Comment: Well you created a column named ReferenceID. You then stated it is the primary key of your datatable but you provided no values for it. If you are using a stored procedure to populate your datatable just remove all the unnecessary column definitions. Just create a new DataTable and then call your Fill method.

Comment: @Fabulous the error I'm getting this line on (and catching the exception) is on the sqlAdp.Fill. And @Sean I understand that it is set as a primary key, but it doesn't mean that I cannot set a primary key than populate the values, no? However, reading the Fill command on MSDN, it seems that the `Fill` will only obtain the first result?

Comment: @SeanLange I think you're right. I held off on commenting thinking it's possible that parameter to the stored procedure was not getting a value but had missed that line.

Comment: If this is the case, and I do need to have my primary key added by the end of this since I'm going to be potentially adding more values that are duplicates to this, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Well....you could name the column the same as the column in your query. Why do you need to have a primary key defined in your DataTable anyway?

Comment: I'm going to be implementing this query as a CLR soon here, and I need a list of all "ReferenceIDs" that meet certain criteria across different tables. So I don't want to run into duplicates when I check for Reference IDs across three tables is all mainly, and I'd rather not send XML through CLR right now, and there is no table reference in CLR. Basically I gotta make sure I just have unique values is all within the DataTable so I can continue to make other calls with the values I retrieve! It's a terrible explanation probably but that's the gist of it. I'll look into doing that though, thanks

Comment: Annnnnnnd I'm dumb. You're totally right about setting the primary key as well. I was returning a different name `Select ReferenceID as Item` initially. Changed it, added the primary key back, used a data set instead of a data table (to copy all values) and now it's good to go. Thank you so much for pointing out my small error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining a not null primary key data column in your table called "ReferenceID":

```
Dim dtCol As New DataColumn()
dtCol.ColumnName = "ReferenceID"
dtCol.DataType = GetType(SqlInt32)
dtCol.AllowDBNull = False
```

However, your sql query is not selecting a 1ReferenceID1 column, it is selecting a column named `ID`:

```
Select ID 
From TableName 
Where Reference = @Reference
```

Therefore, when you go to fill your table you get the error:

> Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

Because the not-null, unique constraint you set on "ReferenceID" is being violated.

Change your query to:

```
Select ID as [ReferenceId]
From TableName 
Where Reference = @Reference
```

And you should be set (assuming that that `ID` is unique and not null)